# Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k =cx-x\ln(x)+x\ln(1-x) $ for $0 < x < 1$ for some real $c$? If so, what is $c$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, power-series, eulerian-numbers

Let
$g_k(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k
$
and
$G(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k
$.

For $0 < x < 1$
is
$G(x)
=cx-x\ln(x)+x\ln(1-x)
$
for some real $c$
and, if so,
what is the value of $c$?

I am not sure that
$G(x)$ converges
for any $x$.
The order of summation
can certainly not be reversed.

I am confident of
this analysis of the
$g_k(x)$.

$\begin{array}\\
g_k'(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}n^k\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}n^{k+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{x}g_{k+1}(x)\\
\text{so}\\
g_{k+1}(x)
&=xg_k'(x)\\
\end{array}
$

From this
I can show that
$g_k(x)
=\dfrac{xh_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}
$
where
$h_k(x)$
is a polynomial
of degree $k-1$
with coefficients
that appear to be
the Eulerian numbers.

The following analysis
assumes that
$G(x)$ does converge
and is term-by-term
differentiable.

Therefore
(and this may not be true
because of convergence problems)

$\begin{array}\\
G'(x)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k'(x)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{x}g_{k+1}(x)\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_{k+1}(x)\\
&=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g_{k}(x)\\
&=\dfrac1{x}(-g_0(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_{k}(x))\\
&=\dfrac1{x}(-\dfrac{x}{1-x}+G(x))\\
&=-\dfrac1{1-x}+\dfrac1{x}G(x)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{x}{1-x}
&=G(x)-xG'(x)\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac{1}{x(1-x)}
&=\dfrac{G(x)-xG'(x)}{x^2}\\
&=-(G(x)x^{-1})'\\
\\
(G(x)x^{-1})'
&=\dfrac{-1}{x(1-x)}\\
&=-\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac1{1-x}\\
G(x)x^{-1}
&=c-\ln(x)+\ln(1-x)
\qquad\text{for some } c\\
G(x)
&=cx-x\ln(x)+x\ln(1-x)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 < x < 1$ and all $k \ge 0$ is
$$
g_k(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}
$$
so that
$$
G(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k(x)
$$
is *not* convergent (the terms $g_k(x)$ do not converge to zero). More precisely, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k(x)$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Also $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k$ is a double series of nonnegative terms. If it were convergent (for some $x$) then it would be absolutely convergent, and the order of summation could be interchanged:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  x^nn^k
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  n^k
$$
But $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  n^k$ diverges for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

A formal consideration. In terms of the [Eulerian polynomials](https://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials)
$$
g_k (x) = \frac{{xA_k (x)}}{{(1 - x)^{k + 1} }},
$$
whence
$$
G(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{xA_k (x)}}{{(1 - x)^{k + 1} }}} .
$$
By the [exponential generating function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials#Definition) of the Eulerian polynomials
$$
\frac{x}{{{\rm e}^{ - z}  - x}} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{xA_k (x)}}{{(1 - x)^{k + 1} }}\frac{{z^k }}{{k!}}} .
$$
Hence, formally,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{xA_k (x)}}{{(1 - x)^{k + 1} }}}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - z}x }}{{{\rm e}^{ - z}  - x}}{\rm d}z}  = x\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}z}}{{1 - x{\rm e}^z }}}  =  - x\log x + x\log (x - 1).
$$

Comment: I must admit that I have difficulties to interpret the last identity
$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{xA_k (x)}}{{(1 - x)^{k + 1} }}} =  - x\log x + x\log (x - 1)$ “formally.” What does that mean, in particular if $\log(x-1)$ is not even defined for $0< x < 1$?

Comment: Maybe it should be $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: The integral makes sense if $x>1$.