# Generating function of $(-1)^n(n+1)^k$

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The power series $\displaystyle f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)^k x^n$ is of the form
$$\frac{p_{k-1}(x)}{(1+x)^{k+1}}$$
where $p_{k-1}(x)$ is a degree $k-1$ polynomial satisfying the following conditions.

1. $p_0(x)=1$
2. $p_{k}(x)=p_{k-1}(x)+x(1+x)p_{k-1}'(x)-kxp_{k-1}(x)$

The second condition follows from termwise multiplication by $x$ and differentiation:
$$f_{k+1}(x)=(xf_k(x))'.$$

The first few $p_k(x)$ are
\begin{align*}
p_1(x)&=1-x\\
p_2(x)&=1-4x+x^2\\
p_3(x)&=1-11x+11x^2-x^3\\
p_4(x)&=1-26x+66x^2-26x^3+x^4
\end{align*}
One can see that the coefficients of $p_k(x)$ are alternating in sign and symmetric in magnitude.

**Question:** is there a closed-form formula for $p_k(x)$ (or its coefficients) for a general natural number $k$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states

> The power series $\displaystyle f_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)^k x^n$ is of the form
> $$\frac{p_{k-1}(x)}{(1+x)^{k+1}}$$

The (unsigned) polynomial cofficients appear in the
[OEIS sequence A008292](https://oeis.org/A008292).

> $\texttt{Triangle of Eulerian numbers T(n,k) (n >= 1, 1 <= k <= n) read by rows.}$

> $\texttt{The polynomials E(z,n) = numerator(Sum_{k>=1} (-1)^(n+1)*k^n*z^(k-1))}$ $\texttt{for n >=1 lead directly to the triangle of Eulerian numbers.}$

> $\texttt{1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 11, 11, 1, 1, 26, 66, 26, 1, 1, 57, 302, 302, 57, 1,}$

> $\texttt{T(n, k) = k * T(n-1, k) + (n-k+1) * T(n-1, k-1), T(1, 1) = 1.}$
> $\texttt{T(n, k) = Sum_{j=0..k} (-1)^j * (k-j)^n * binomial(n+1, j).}$

Use Mathematica to sum the infinite series as

```
Sum[(-z)^n*(n+1)^k, {n,0,Infinity}]
(* -(PolyLog[-k, -z]/z) *)

(* example for p_3(x) *)
Sum[ (-z)^n*(n+1)^(3+1), {n, 0, Infinity}]
(* (1 - 11*z + 11*z^2 - z^3)/(1 + z)^5 *)
-PolyLog[-4, -z]/z //Simplify
(* (1 - 11*z + 11*z^2 - z^3)/(1 + z)^5 *)
```

The general result is that
$$ p_k(x) = -\text{Li}_{-k-1}( -x) $$
where $\,\text{Li}_n(x)\,$ is the
[polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

The answer to the question

> **Question:** is there a closed-form formula for $p_k(x)$ (or its coefficients) for a general natural number $k$?

is "yes" for $p_k(x)$ if you consider the polylogarithm or
[Eulerian polynomials](https://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials)
closed-form.

Alternatively, the finite summation for the coefficients

$$ \sum_{j=0}^n -(-1)^{n-j} (n-j)^k {{k+1}\choose j} $$

could be considered closed-form because it is a finite
sum, but that is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First,obtain the formula of:
$$F(N,q) = \sum\limits_{{\rm{n = }}0}^{N - 1} {{q^n}} f(n),q \ne 0,1$$
Second,obtain the limit expression：
$$L(q) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to \infty } F(N,q),0 < q < 1$$
then L(x) is the answer.Eulerian Polynomials A(M,t) is  a special case of f(n)=n<sup>M</sup>.
In this case:
$$\eqalign{
  & {p_k}(x) = \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{k + 1} {g!{S_2}(k + 2,g + 1)} {(1 + x)^{k + 1 - g}}{( - x)^g}  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{k + 1} {{{( - 1)}^{k + 1 - g}}g!{S_2}(k + 1,g)} {(1 + x)^{k + 1 - g}} = \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{k + 1} {\left\langle {_g^k} \right\rangle } {( - x)^g} \cr} $$

$$\left\langle {_g^k} \right\rangle {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} is{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} Eulerian{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} Numbers,{S_2}(k,g){\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} is{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} Stirling{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} Number{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} of{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} the{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} \sec ond{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} kind$$

[Formal Calculations](https://www.preprints.org/manuscript/202305.0311/v1) has various expressions and widespread generalizations of Eulerian polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this as part of this question:

[Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nn^k =cx-x\ln(x)+x\ln(1-x) $ for $0 < x < 1$ for some real $c$? If so, what is $c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719185/does-sum-k-0-infty-sum-n-1-infty-xnnk-cx-x-lnxx-ln1-x-for)

The other part was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here we derive the coefficients of $p_k$ and show $p_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k$.

> We obtain for $k\geq 1$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{p_{k-1}(x)}&=(1+x)^{k+1}f_k(x)\\
> &=\left(\sum_{m=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{m}x^m\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+1)^kx^n\right)\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{{m+n=q}\atop{m,n\geq 0}}\atop{m\leq k+1}}
> \binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^m(n+1)^k\right)x^q\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\min\{q,k+1\}}\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^{q-m}(q-m+1)^k\right)x^q\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{k-1}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{q}\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^{q-m}(q-m+1)^k\right)x^q}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
> Note that we claim in (3) that $p_{k-1}$ a polynomial of degree $\leq k-1$ which is not obvious and has to be shown.

When looking at the coefficient of $x^q, 0\leq q\leq k-1$ of $p_{k-1}$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^q]p_{k-1}(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{q}\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^{q-m}(q-m+1)^k}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
we see the finite sum (4) is *not* in closed form. See for instance the reasoning of R. P. Stanley given in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4421120/what-does-the-formal-definition-of-closed-form-say-about-finite-sums-exactly/4421838#4421838)*.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply out the series using Cauchy multiplication.
- In (2) we eliminate $n$ replacing it with $q-m$. We also take care when setting the upper index of the inner sum. We note that $\binom{k+1}{m}=0$ if $m>k+1$.
- In (3) we claim we have a polynomial of degree $\leq k-1$. In order to show it we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
  \begin{align*}
  m^k=k![z^k]e^{mz}
  \end{align*}
  We claim
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\sum_{m=0}^q\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^{q-m}(q-m+1)^k=0\qquad\qquad q\geq k}\tag{5}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain for $q\geq k$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{m=0}^{k+1}}&\color{blue}{\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^m(q-m+1)^k}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^mk![z^k]e^{(q-m+1)z}\tag{7}\\
> &=k![z^k]e^{(q+1)z}\sum_{m=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{m}(-1)^me^{-mz}\\
> &=k![z^k]e^{(q+1)z}\left(1-e^z\right)^{k+1}\tag{8}\\
> &=k![z^k]e^{(q+1)z}\left(-z-\frac{z^2}{2}-\cdots\right)^{k+1}\tag{9}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (5) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (6) we set the upper limit of the sum to $k+1$ since $\binom{k+1}{m}=0$ if $q>k+1$. If $q=k$ we can also set the upper limit to $k+1$ since in this case we have $(k-m+1)^k=0$ if $m=k+1$.
- In (7) we apply (5) and use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator in the next line.
- In (8) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (9) we expand the exponential function noting that it contains exponents of $z$ always greater than $k$. Since $e^{(q+1)z}=1+(q+1)z+\cdots$ contains exponents of $z$ greater or equal to zero, the coefficient of $z^k$ in (9) is zero.